# Set two digits for correlogram, but some values were rounded up to one

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I tried to create a correlogram with all values having two decimal places, but some of them still only have one.

I used both codes but didn't help

```
corrplot(round(corr(M)),2)
corrplot(M,number.digits=2)
```

Comment: Have you had a look into format functions?